# Unable to clone on my MAC using terminal commands

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-clone, azure-repos

I am using macbook, I have been trying to clone the repository using "git clone" command from azure repos using https link. but somewhere I am getting an issue, i could not clone it every time i tried. below is the syntax of my command

> tk0991@INHYIMAC0017 projectFolder %  git clone "link of my repo"

below is the fatal error i am getting

> fatal: unable to access 'link of my repo' : Operation timed out after 300035 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

link of my repo is actual http link of my repository provided by azure when I clicked on clone in repos tab

I hope I will get some help on this.

Comment: Is this being done on your home machine or maybe a workplace one? Anyways it seems like you're not getting a response from the server, that can happen due to many reasons. Maybe a firewall on your machine or somewhere on the network is not letting the data through. What kind of link are you using? Is it a https link or is it an ssh?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, I am using http link. the machine is provided by my employer

Comment: Indeed it seems as a firewall issue most probably on the firewall device. First try to download a public repository from github by using its URL. Then you can verify that there is not a problem with your repository and its a common problem on your computer

Comment: @GeralexGR Tried the public repo from git, getting the same error. I dont know whether I can turn off firewall or not because, I should connect VPN and then only I can access repo. I will give it a try by turning off firewall

Comment: @phanikumar it may be a firewall configuration on the router layer, as a result only your network admin can allow this change. As a quick solution you could try to download the repository on another machine and email it on your computer

Comment: @GeralexGR yeah, I just checked my firewall settings, its been turned off already.